# How do I disable Magnifier's "smoothing" filter in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, zoom, pixels, magnifier

I would prefer to have a "nearest-neighbor" scale mode in the Magnifier (where each original pixels is rendered as a large square, not blurred between eachother).

Is there an option to change that, or a Registry tweak even to do this?

Comment: There's some users claiming this only appears blurry when using the "Classic Theme" which I am using, and I don't want to change that.

Comment: Easy (probably only) answer: Use a different magnifier tool.

Comment: If by that you mean Sysinternals' ZoomIt program, no thanks - it zooms the whole screen instead of showing the target area in it's own window.

Comment: @bigp I think he meant any proprietary/custom made magnifier, like http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

As [@TWiStErRob](https://superuser.com/users/145861/twisterrob) suggested in the comments, using [magnifier.sourceforge.net](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/) resolved this for me. Using this tool, I can clearly see the individual pixels I wanted to see, in "nearest neighbor" presentation.